# Image not found using angular material

Tags: angular, image

I get this error when trying to display an image:

http://localhost:4200/daily-process/src/WebUI/Angular/src/images/DailyProcessBlack.png 404 (Not Found)

I put the image in a mat-card and I can see the image when I navigate to the folder path but it doesn't show on the site:

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
 <mat-card-header>
<div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
 </mat-card-header>
<img mat-card-image src="/daily-process/src/WebUI/Angular/src/images/DailyProcessBlack.png" 
alt="Image">  
</mat-card>
```

**angular.json**

```
 {
 "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
 "version": 1,
 "newProjectRoot": "projects",
 "projects": {
  "daily-process": {
  "projectType": "application",
  "schematics": {},
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/daily-process",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        // "styles": [
        //   "src/styles.css"
        // ],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb",
              "maximumError": "10kb"
            }
          ],
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "daily-process:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "daily-process:build:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "daily-process:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        // "styles": [
        //   "src/styles.css"
        // ],
         "scripts": []
        }
      }
    }
  }
 },
 "defaultProject": "daily-process"
}
```

**Image of folder structure**
[image]

Can someone please provide a reason why and a solution to what I need to do to get this to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `angular.json` there is an array called `assets`

These are the default values

```json
"assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
```

This is where angular will host files / images. You can put your assets in `src/assets`, or you can add your own paths.

There are two copies of the `assets` array - one for the `build` command and one for the `test` command, so make sure to keep them synchronized.

Comment: I already had two copies of that in the angular.json file. I put the code for that file in my original post.

Comment: try changing path to just `assets/images/DailyProcessBlack.png` without the prefix. If that doesn't work, add `src/assets/images` to the assets array or move your image to the base `assets` folder. I believe if you look in your `dist` folder you'll see the actual folder structure that is being hosted by `ng serve`.

Comment: Changing the path, did it!! Thanks so much Chris.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to put that image in assets folder inside your app, and the route you need to add is assets/images/DailyProcessBlack.png
If you have problem with that route try to test local or global route, but you need to add the image inside assets, otherwise you would have to modify the angular.json file

Comment: I create new folder assets, put the images folder inside of assets folder and the image still doesn't show. Here is the new path: /daily-process/src/WebUI/Angular/src/assets/images/DailyProcessBlack.png

Comment: can you show the folder structure, i.e. in which component is this image src being used in?

Comment: I put an image of the folder structure in my original post.